# Sendkeys method not entering the @ in the text box in windows desktop application using appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-java

Using the sendkeys to enter the '@' in the email id field is not working, instead of '@' the 'G' is getting entered.

sample Email: `Grady@gmail.com`
Output in the email using selenium: GradyGgmail.com

code snippet:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        
String email = "Gradya@gmail.com.com";

WebElement send = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//Edit[starts-with(@ClassName,'BaseTextField_QMLTYPE')][@Name='Email']"));
action.sendKeys(send, email).perform();
```

Note: I am performing this action on the Desktop Application in windows
using Appium

Comment: Please add the code snippet.

Comment: Please add the version of `Appium` used, driver used which will help to get more relevant information

Answer (score 0):

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
this one is not supported for Version 4.17.0